# Cannot update file upload form, still no proccess to database in php

Tags: php, mysql, upload

my script aims to edit the uploaded files in the database, but when I run my script, the editing process is not running, if there are any additional scripts or there are any of my scripts? help me please.

```
<?php 
require 'config.php'; 
    if(isset($_POST['btn-edit']))
    {    
        $tgl = $_POST['tgl'];
        $no_surat = $_POST['no_surat'];
        $perihal = $_POST['perihal'];
        $asal_surat = $_POST['asal_surat'];
        $tujuan_surat = $_POST['tujuan_surat'];
        $no_rak = $_POST['no_rak'];
        $no_index = $_POST['no_index'];
        $jenis_surat = $_POST['jenis_surat']; 
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder="uploads/";
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;
        $final_file = strtolower($file);

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
            {
                $sql="update surat set tgl = '$tgl', no_surat = '$no_surat', perihal = '$perihal', asal_surat = '$asal_surat', tujuan_surat = '$tujuan_surat', no_rak = '$no_rak', no_index = '$no_index', file = '$final_file', jenis_surat = '$jenis_surat' WHERE id = '$id'";
                mysql_query($sql);
                header('location:index.php?act=update');
            }
                else
            {
                header('location:index.php?act=fail');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is your file upload part working?